# Alternate to disc method to find volume of a solid of revolution

Tags: integration, volume

The main, and correct, method to finding the volume of a solid of revolution is by using the disc method, whereby you split the solid into numerous discs with a small thickness, say $\delta x$, and find the sum of the volumes of these discs. As $\delta x$ gets smaller, i.e. by taking the limit to 0, we calculate the volue of the whole solid of revolution.

This gives the following equation:

$Volume = \pi\int_a^b y^2 \delta x$

I understand how this works however am not sure why the following method doesn't work:

First; find the area under the curve of the function by simply doing $ Area = \int_a^b y \delta x$

Second; rotate this area by $360^o = 2\pi r$, where $r = y$ giving $Volume = 2\pi y\int_a^b y \delta x $

Ofcourse, this is not the correct equation to calculate the volume of a solid of revolution.

Why is this method wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what your formula $2\pi y\int_a^b y \delta x$ means. Could you please include a worked example in your question, showing how you would apply this formula to a simple problem such as the volume of the cone swept out by $y=x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, so we can see how you think this is supposed to work?